# Ansible use inventory_hostname or ansible_hostname in task name

Tags: ansible

I am writing a rolling upgrade playbook and would like to print out the hostname of current host been upgraded.

I put `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_hostname` in task names but that did not work

```
- name: upgrade softare on {{inventory_hostname}}
- name: current host is {{ansible_hostname}}
```

debug works fine

```
- name: Test a variable
  debug: var=inventory_hostname

TASK: [Test a variable] ******************************************************* 
ok: [SERV14] => {
    "var": {
        "inventory_hostname": "SERV14"
    }
}
```

So what should I do to be able to use those variables in task name descriptions.

Thanks

Comment: Currently, variable substitution can not be done in name. See [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3103)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Starting from v2.0 Ansible supports variable substitution in task/handler names: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10347, so these examples will work as expected:

```
- name: upgrade software on {{inventory_hostname}}
- name: current host is {{ansible_hostname}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write the `{{ ansible_hostname }}` after the `tasks:`, because before that it hasn't yet gathered the facts so it can't give the result. I may be wrong on the concept but in practice it was successful.

```
tasks:
  - name: Install the httpd on {{ ansible_hostname }}
    yum: 
      name: httpd 
      state: latest
```

[image: playbook]

[image: play output]